# Real projective $n$ space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

We define $\sim$ on $\mathbf{R}^n - \{0\}$ by $x \sim y$ if $x = \lambda y$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbf{R}$. We define projective $n$ space by $X = (\mathbf{R}^n - \{0\})/{\sim}$.

I am having trouble showing that $X$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional topological manifold. The definition of a topological manifold that I'm working with is the following: $X$ is a topological $n$-manifold if, for all $x \in X$, there is an open nhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$.

I understand that one can take $U$ to be homeomorphic to any open ball in $\mathbf{R}^n$, or any open nhood ball in $\mathbf{R}^n$.

I am also aware that the open nhoods of $\overline{x} \in X$ will look like a half-sphere (at least I think so; I think my work was OK here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If $[x_0:\cdots:x_n]\in X$ corresponds to the line $\lambda(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ and $x_i\neq0$, then $[x_0:\cdots:x_n]=[x_0/x_i:\cdots:x_{i-1}/x_i:1:x_{i+1}/x_i:\cdots:x_n/x_i]$.

Now on the open set $U_i=\{[x_0:\cdots:x_n]\in X:x_i\neq0\}$, take the chart $U_i\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $[x_0:\cdots:x_n]\mapsto(x_0/x_i,\ldots,x_n/x_i)$ (with the $i$-th coordinate removed).

**EDIT** I realize I used $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ mod the action of $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$ as in the question above. Sorry!

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I should have been trying to show that $X$ is an $n-1$ manifold. I misread the exercise I was trying to do.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for using $n+1$ instead of $n$!